# How to detect iPhone or Android device in Salesforce LWC not Aura?

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to detect iPhone or Android device in Salesforce LWC not Aura ?
Form Factor in LWC does not tell us whether device is Android Phone or iPhone or iPad.

Comment: Here is a similar [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278750/can-we-get-browser-context-in-lwc), which may help you.

Comment: SFSE link, gives browser details.

Comment: well, it's what is usually used. From what I know you don't have other way than User-agent string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NavigatorID.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) read-only property returns the user agent string for the current browser. Since [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) supports `SecureWindow.navigator` property starting from `46.0` you can get some agent info in LWC.

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Navigator extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(navigator.userAgent); // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Chrome/90.0.4430.212
    }
}
```

Then you can parse that returned info to detect the user agent OS:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

const { userAgent } = navigator;
export default class Navigator extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.isWindows); // true
        console.log(this.isIOS);     // false
        console.log(this.isAndroid); // false
    }

    get isIOS() {
        return userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) != null;
    }

    get isAndroid() {
        return userAgent.match(/Android/i) != null;
    }

    get isWindows() {
        return userAgent.match(/Windows/i) != null;
    }

    get isUnix() {
        return userAgent.match(/Unix/i) != null;
    }
    
    get isMac() {
        return userAgent.match(/Mac/i) != null && !this.isIOS;
    }
    
    get isLinux() {
        return userAgent.match(/Linux/i) != null && !this.isAndroid;
    }
    
    get isBlackBerry() {
        return userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) != null;
    }
    
}
```

**Disclaimer**

> Browser identification based on detecting the user agent string is **unreliable** and **is not recommended**, as the user agent string is user configurable. For example:

- In Firefox, you can change the preference `general.useragent.override` in `about:config`. Some Firefox extensions do that; however, this only changes the HTTP header that gets sent, and doesn't affect browser detection performed by JavaScript code.
- Opera 6+ allows users to set the browser identification string via a menu.
- Microsoft Internet Explorer uses the Windows registry.
- Safari and iCab allow users to change the browser user agent string to predefined Internet Explorer or Netscape strings via a menu.

Comment: Thank You Oleh for Reply. Will try this :-)

Comment: Hi Oleh ! I have verified this on my Android mobile with the help of @track variable and it is working as expected. Thank You Very Much.